# How do I make the animation continue to work if I switched the tab (CSS, JS)

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a complex multi-layer animation that I made using Keyframes and JS animation events. This animation is overlaid with an audio track. To make the visual part match the text on the audio, I use setTimeout.

When I switch browser tabs, the audio track continues to play, but the animation stops. The customer's requirement is that the animation should continue along with the sound even when switching tabs.

How can I do this?

Comment: Since they are "synced" while the tab is focused, but the animation stops (to save cpu resources I would imagine) but not the audio, you could have some periodic code in place that uses the position of the audio to determine the correct position of the animation. ... It will get hairy, I know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common browser feature to save on computational resources. When the user's tab becomes hidden (e.g. switching to a new tab), the browser will hault most of the activity in the UI.

You can solve this by using a combination of `requestAnimationFrame` and a bit of maths.

Since you have not shared a code example, here is a high-level approach of how to achieve this. This will keep animations in sync by using timestamps:

```js
const startTime = Date.now();
const duration = 2000;

// This is a mapping (or translation) function, which takes a value (ranging from 
// x1 to x2) and maps (or translates) it to a new value (ranging from x2 to y2)
const map = (n, x1, y1, x2, y2) =>
  Math.min(Math.max(((n - x1) * (y2 - x2)) / (y1 - x1) + x2, x2), y2);

let frame;
(function animate() {
  frame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  const delta = Date.now() - startTime;
  // t is a normalized value from 0 to 1.
  // t is 0 when the animation is at the beginning and 1 when at the end
  const t = map(delta, 0, duration, 0, 1);

  // Do something with t. Here's an example of animating a number from 0 to 100,
  // but you could also animate anything, e.g. by mapping t to a new set of values
  console.log(Math.floor(map(t, 0, 1, 0, 100)));

  // Stop the animation loop when t reaches 1
  if (t === 1) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(frame);
  }
})();
```

You can test this yourself, by running the animation, switching tabs, and returning. Since the animation now uses the `startTime` and a derived delta from `now - startTime` the animation will always be in sync.